# Probability of getting an outlier in a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given $ N $ data points that fit a normal distribution, what is the probability that the $ N+1^{th} $ data point is further away from the mean of the distribution than the previous $ N $ data points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $N$ points and the parameters $\mu, \sigma$ of the distribution are given, find the distance $r$ of the farthest point from $\mu$, and the probability is
$2 \Phi(-r/\sigma)$.  If the $N$ points are not given, any ordering of the distances of the $N+1$ points are equally likely, so $1/(N+1)$.

Comment: this is very informative! thank you!